# TypeError expected string or bytes-like object - Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't find why is this error is happening.

> `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

I am trying to get the time that 'Huffington Post' appears as sponsor, using the code:

```py
polls = list(set(covid_approval_polls["sponsor"]))

Huff_Post_regexp = r"\bHuffington Post\b"

Huff_Post = [
   approval 
   for approval in polls 
   if re.search(Huff_Post_regexp, approval) is not None
]
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
 start_date    end_date         pollster    sponsor  sample_size population  \
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist       1500.0          a   
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        376.0          a   
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        523.0          a   
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        599.0          a   
4  2020-02-07  2020-02-09  Morning Consult        NaN       2200.0          a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments of the `re.search` must be "string" or "byte". As I see in your "sponser" column, there is a **NaN** which interpreted as `float` so in that iteration `approval` is neither string nor byte. This is why you get that TypeError.

Write this code to see that in action:

```
for item in list(set(covid_approval_polls["sponsor"])):
    print(item, type(item))
```

To solve this, you can either ignore the `re.search` with single condition `pd.isna()` or maybe replace the NaNs in DataFrame with empty string `""`.